# Extent Reports 3.1.5 not appending after each test run

Tags: extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I am use Extent Reports 3.1.5 and my reports keep getting overwritten on each test run. I have implemented to the bests of my ability the solution found on stack-overflow and various sites and no progress. I have spent 24 hours troubleshooting this issue and need help.

I even went and examined the following sites http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/3/java/#htmlreporter-features
http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/3/java/#htmlreporter-features
and check my code and still could not find the issue. If there is something i am overlooking please help me.

Again my test runs however it only writes the last test ran in my testng.xml file

This is my Base Test Class:

```
package test;

public class BaseTest {

      //-------Page Objects----------
      login_Page objBELogin;
      poll_Page objCreatePoll;
      survey_Page objCreateSurvey;
      task_Page objCreateTaskGroup;
      discussion_Page objCreateDiscussion;
      userprofile_Page objUserProfile;
      event_Page objectEvent;
      workgroup_Page objectWorkgroup;
      workroom_Page objectWorkroom;


      //-----------------------------
      static WebDriver driver;
      static String homePage = "https://automation-ozzie.boardeffect.com/login";

      ExtentReports report;
      ExtentTest test;//--parent test



    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() throws InterruptedException{
        //--------Extent Report--------
        report = ExtentFactory.getInstance();
        //-----------------------------
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\GRID\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
        option.addArguments("disable-infobars");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(option);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get(homePage);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void register(Method method) {
        String testName = method.getName();
        test = report.createTest(testName);

    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void catureStatus(ITestResult result) {
        if (result.getStatus()==ITestResult.SUCCESS) {
            test.log(Status.PASS,"Test Method named as : "+ result.getName()+" is passed");

        }else if(result.getStatus()==ITestResult.FAILURE) {
            test.log(Status.PASS,"Test Method named as : "+ result.getName()+" is FAILED");
            test.log(Status.FAIL,"Test failure : "+ result.getThrowable());
        }
        else if(result.getStatus()==ITestResult.SKIP) {
            test.log(Status.PASS,"Test Method named as : "+ result.getName()+" is skipped");
        }

    }




    @AfterClass
      public void tearDown() throws InterruptedException {
        report.flush();
        driver.quit();



      }

}





public class ExtentFactory {

    public static ExtentReports getInstance() {
        ExtentHtmlReporter html = new ExtentHtmlReporter("surefire-reports//Extent.html");
        html.setAppendExisting(true);
        ExtentReports extent = new ExtentReports();
        extent.attachReporter(html);
        return extent;

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider adding a unique name to report file for each run.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class ExtentFactory {

    public static ExtentReports getInstance() {

        String out = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh-mm-ss'.html'").format(new Date());
        ExtentHtmlReporter html = new ExtentHtmlReporter("surefire-reports//"+out);
        ExtentReports extent = new ExtentReports();
        extent.attachReporter(html);
        return extent;

    }

}
```

You will also need to move the report instance creation to @beforesuite, so that it runs only once for the entire test suite.

```
@BeforeSuite
    public void OneTimesetUp() throws InterruptedException{
        //--------Extent Report--------
        report = ExtentFactory.getInstance();
        //-----------------------------

}
```

Comment: ah! okay will try this.